# XCode Variable Info Window?

Tags: xcode, variables, window

I dont know what this window is called in XCode.
The yellow box with the shadow behind it.
In any case, how can I FORCE this window to appear, because it seems incredibly arbitrary when it decides to show up during a running debugging session.  Sometimes I get luck and hover the mouse around in just the right magical way that it appears, other times, on the same variable, I'm not so lucky and all the hovering in the world won't make it appear.  Really annoying the way it works, so there must be a way to force it to appear.

Yes I'm aware that there are several other ways to see variable values, but I happen to like this particular way because it's so quick and straightforward when it actually works.  You don't have to expand your way through a tree of variable subvalues in order to find a deeply nested value which can be easily displayed on the spot via this popup window.

[image: Supplementary variable info]

Answer (score 0):

This info only pops up when your app is running, so you could use that info for debugging. When you stop the app, you can't see that information.

There is also Variables View in Xcode. You can 'pause' the execution of code using breakpoints, then you can view the values of variables in your code.

For more information read this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html

Comment: True, like Visual Studio, it only pops up when the app is running, I did know that.  I edited my post to clarify that I meant "when running"  It seems that this window is only available hovering over certain kinds of variables, and also only available if you hover juuuuust right, because sometimes, I can hover over a variable and get the window, and other times, over the same variable (app still running) it won't appear.